# next-auth session.user is empty after successful login

Tags: next.js, next-auth

After user successfully logged into it's account (next-auth), I want to access it's data when clicking on a button. The login system is based on phone and sms verification.

My `[...nextauth].js` code:

```
export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        phone: {
          label: "phone",
          type: "text",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
          ...

          return user;
        }
      },
      callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
          return { ...token, id: user.id };
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
          const id = token.id;
          return { ...session, id };
        },
      },
      session: {
        jwt: true,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

It looks `jwt` and `sesssion` callbacks won't uodate

My `component` code:

```
export const Component = () => {
  const {data: session} = useSession();
  const handleClick() => {
    ...
    console.log(JSON.stringify(session)) //returns {user:{}, expireDate: "...."}
    ...
  }
```

}

Comment: try to check if a user is there then set it `token.accessToken = user.access_token` then return the token as well as userId.